# HttpContext.Current.Cache clears after while

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm using `HttpContext` cache in a console application and after a while(2 or 3 hours) `HttpContext` cache is removed automatically. How to stop clearing cache??

```
private List<Model.CacheModel> _CompleteList = null;
public List<Model.CacheModel> CompleteList
{
   get
   {
       if (_CompleteList == null)
       {
           _CompleteList = (HttpContext.Current.Cache["CompleteList"] as List<Model.CacheModel>);
            if (_CompleteList == null)
            {
              _CompleteList = new List<Model.CacheModel>();
               HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("CompleteList", _CompleteList);
            }
       }

       return _CompleteList;
    }

    set
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("CompleteList", _CompleteList);
    }
 }
```

This is where I use this property

```
public void GetControl(List<Model.CacheModel> List)
{

        var CahcedList = (HttpContext.Current.Cache["CompleteList"] as List<Model.CacheModel>);
        if (CahcedList == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache["CompleteList"] = List;
        }
        else
        {
            if (CahcedList.LastOrDefault().Time != List.LastOrDefault().Time)
            {
               CahcedList.Remove(CahcedList.FirstOrDefault());
               CahcedList.Add(List.LastOrDefault());        
               Clients.Others.broadcastAll(
                  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(List.LastOrDefault()));
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That's what the cache is meant to do - keep *some* expensive data in memory, so you don't have to recalculate it. The real question should be why are you trying to store infrequently used data in the cache in the first place? If that data isn't use for 2 hours, what's the point of caching it?

Comment: If you wanted a permanent in-memory store, you could register a *concurrent* container as a Singleton.

Comment: In any case, this code has concurrency issues. The cache may be thread-safe but the `List<>` inside it isn't. Those `Add` and `Remove` calls can throw due to concurrency conflicts while the results of `FirstOrDefault` or `LastOrDefault()` can change from one line to the next.

Comment: If you want in-memory storage, a singleton ConcurrentQueue would work without locking. No need for `LastOrDefault()`, you can use `TryPeek` to check the last item safely, `TryDequeue` to remove it

Comment: @panagiotisKanavos My program is single thread and called every 30 seconds, so actually its not multi thread and call at the same time, how concurrency  happens??

Comment: In that case you don't need a cache *at all*. A single global static `CompleteList` property would be fine. You can create a class that wraps over a `List<>` or `Queue<>` to enforce the lookup, removal logic. If you use DI, you could register that class as a Singleton instead of using a singleton property.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, the cache will be cleared on the following scenarios:

1. The code manually clears an entry.
       By using the `Remove` method of the `Cache` object.
2. The cache entry expires.
      By using the `absoluteExpiration` or `slidingExpiration` parameters of the Add and `Insert` methods of the `Cache` object.

3.The host process ends (application or `IIS reset`, `application pool recycle`, etc).

Comment: in this case, where should i use absoluteExpiration or slidingExpiration ?

Comment: @adamjohanson if you want permanent storage *don't* use the Cache in the first place.

Comment: at the time of insert cache . follow this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/18c1wd61%28v%3dvs.140%29